# What is the difference between core.stdc.stdlib.malloc and core.memory.GC.malloc?

Tags: d

What is the difference between `core.stdc.stdlib.malloc` and `core.memory.GC.malloc`? Which of these should I use when a program runs with GC disabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`core.stdc.stdlib.malloc` is plain C's malloc, so memory is not registred to `GC`. This means it will not be scanned and you must use C's `free` to free this memory. `core.memory.GC.malloc` is registred by `GC` and it will be scanned. You can use both of them. But if you use `GC.disable` even memory alloceted by `core.memory.GC.malloc` would not be freed until you enable GC back, or you call `GC.collect`.

Btw. if you want better control over memory allocation you should look at https://dlang.org/phobos/std_experimental_allocator.html